# How to avoid multiple label in zoomin in tilemill

Tags: tilemill, cartocss

Now i am working on tilemill ,and i am facing a problem in a tilemill when i am styling zoomin a road layer that time display road layer label multiple times.How can avoid these multiple road labels[image] name in tilemill

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the road in question is made of 2 different lines/ways - potentially to define different road types.

You could try using `text-min-path-length: 3;` (play with the number) to hide labels on short lines.